# Office Add-ins Excel : select range and be able to resize selection like functions parameters

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to select/highlight a range through OfficeJs API and be able to resize it like we can do with functions parameters ?

This is what I would like to do from my office add-in :

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Our team is current working investigate to provide this capability via API, would you please share us the scenario? we would like to see if we can cover your scenario.

Comment: @RaymondLu, thanks for you answer. We've an Office add-in (Taskpane) where the user can set a range address in a text field. When the textfield is focused, the related range in Excel is highlighted. If the user needs to update the range address, he must edit the address manually in the textfield. A best ux would be to update the address by resizing the selected range or by selecting a new one from Excel.